# Why is my recursion function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, recursion

my a and b variables are coming out to be same each time I reach the return statement in the end with concat. Why when im pushing into array after I pass it to the first recursive function. Why does first one have the updated array?

```js
let subset = function(n, arr) {

    if (n == array.length) {
        return [arr]
    }
    // let a = [...arr] //working fine with this
    // arr.push(arra[n])
    let a = subset(n + 1, arr)
    arr.push(array[n])
    let b = subset(n + 1, arr)

    return a.concat(b)

}
let array = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(subset(0, []))
```

By destructuring my array its working properly. But I dont want to use extra space.

Comment: Both `a` and `b` are assigned to `subset(n+1,arr)`, so why do you expect them to be different?

Comment: I pushed into arr after calling the first subset(), so why does it contain the updated arr in it ?

Comment: Because `push` **updates** an array. It doesn't matter if you have that array referenced at multiple places... it still is one array, and that one array gets an extra element.

Comment: No, it is not about scoping. It is about there being **one** and the same array: the `arr` you pass to the function is still the same array that the caller has a reference to. You somehow seem to think that the array clones itself somewhere and has a variant that starts living a separate life so that the `push` only affects one of the two... But there is nothing in your code that clones the array.

Comment: Ah I didnt know a and b were actually referencing the same array. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Eh, no; `a` and `b` do not reference the same array. `arr` gets referenced in `[arr]`.

Comment: What is this functions supposed to do?

Comment: So basically there is no way to do this with just arr. I'll have to use a destructured copy of arr to do this in order for a and b to refer to different arrays? Im trying to get subsets.

Comment: Since every subset needs to be a separate array, by consequence you will have to refer to different arrays... the space you allocate is not more than you need for the result.

Comment: @trincot if the subsets are only needed one at a time, the underlying array can be reused, then it's up to the consumer to copy if one (or more) subsets need to be stored in memory.

Comment: It is clear the asker is trying to build an array of subarrays.

Answer (score 1):

When the recursion gets to its base case, the returned array has one element, which is `arr`. The caller assigns this wrapped array to `a`. This means that `a[0]` and `arr` are the same array. If then `arr` gets an extra element via the `push` call, then this will also be seen via `a[0]`. You expected that `a[0]` and `arr` would be separate arrays that could live their own lives, but that is not the case.

You *do* create a new *outer* array with `concat`, but that doesn't solve the problem that the *inner* arrays are mutated with `push`.

You write that you don't want to use extra space, but as the goal is to create an array of subarrays, it really is needed to allocate the space for each separate subarray.

There are several other ways to get this done. For instance, it would make sense to create the copy of `arr` at the moment you place it in the *result*. On the other hand you can avoid the creation of a new outer array, and keep extending the existing one.

I would avoid referencing the global `array` variable from within the function: just pass that array as argument too.

```js
let subset = function(array, n=0, arr=[], result=[]) {
    if (n == array.length) {
        result.push([...arr]); //  <--- here we clone arr
    } else {
        subset(array, n + 1, arr, result);
        arr.push(array[n]);
        subset(array, n + 1, arr, result);
        arr.pop(); // Undo the push
    }
    return result;
}
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(subset(array));
```

So in this code, there is only one `arr` array: it grows and shrinks during the whole process. Only when it needs to be put in the result, a copy is made of it ("snapshot"), so that any further manipulation of `arr` will not affect this subarray in the result. There is also only one result array. Both that `arr` and `result` array are created by the default of the function parameters (`[]`).

As an alternative you could use a generator function. Then the caller of that generator function will build the result array:

```js
let subsetIterator = function* (array, n=0, arr=[]) {
    if (n == array.length) return yield [...arr];
    yield* subsetIterator(array, n + 1, arr);
    arr.push(array[n]);
    yield* subsetIterator(array, n + 1, arr);
    arr.pop(); // Undo the push
}
let array = [1, 2, 3];
let result = [...subsetIterator(array)]; // build result array from subarrays
console.log(result);
```

If you don't really need the `result` array, but only want to have the subarrays, then the story changes: in that case you don't *have* to create separate array instances. It is then up to the caller to be aware that the iterator will yield the same (but mutated) array. This is "dangerous" if the caller is not aware of that and is surprised that a previously yielded array still changed after that. But if you know what you are doing it does work:

```js
let subsetIterator = function* (array, n=0, arr=[]) {
    if (n == array.length) return yield arr; // no copy is made!
    yield* subsetIterator(array, n + 1, arr);
    arr.push(array[n]);
    yield* subsetIterator(array, n + 1, arr);
    arr.pop(); // Undo the push
}
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let arr of subsetIterator(array)) console.log(arr);
```

All iterated `arr` are actually the *same* array now, but it gets printed at a different moment in its (mutating) lifetime.